# Responsive navbar won't show up

Tags: javascript, html, css

*SOLVED*
I've created a custom navbar which i've decided to make responsive.

However when I click on the little 'bars' icon, the responsive navbar won't show up?
Source Code: https://jsfiddle.net/spoktry9/

```
  <nav>
    <div class="toggle">

        <i class="fas fa-bars menu" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class= "menu" href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>

      <li><a class= "info" href="info.html">Info</a></li>
      <li><a class= "reserve" href="reserve.html">rReserve</a></li>    
      <li><a class= "pics" href="pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
      <li><a class= "contact" href="contact_index.html">Contact</a></li>
        <div class = "login">
    <a href="login.html"><img src="img/login.png" heigt= "75" ;></a>

  </div>

    </ul>
  </nav>
```

SEE LINK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have parsing errors on jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $('ul').toggleClass('active');
    }
}
```

It should be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $('ul').toggleClass('active');
    });
})
```

The `color` property on your CSS is making the bar not showing up, just make it another color (`color:#000;`) or just simply take it off.

Also, make sure you linked jQuery Library on your HTML code.

[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8tw0z4fa/)